# this error ( remove build tools version and sync project )

Tags: android

please help me with this error since i upgrade my android studio to the last version I'm facing this problem with my code source 
[when i click on ( remove build tools version and sync project )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVHu5.png)

[android studio show me this buildtoolsversion "25.0.2" when i click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUhvT.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCTwp.png)

[i do not know what i should remove in this code help me guys Thank you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4by1B.png)

Comment: Please copy and paste the error messages here directly rather than posting screenshots.

Comment: In the second screen shot, click on the Do Refactor button.

Comment: Thank you for your reply i clikced on Do Refactor button

Comment: and i got this [what i should do now ?][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGfOB.png

Comment: You don't need to do anything about your dependencies. The highlighted lines are only warnings. I suggest that you attempt to build and run your app.

Comment: Note that the only link syntax supported in comments is `[Link text](url)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second screen shot, click on the Do Refactor button.

In the last screenshot, you don't need to do anything. The highlighted lines are only warnings. I suggest that you attempt to build and run your app. When you get it working successfully, you can then evaluate whether or not to upgrade to the most recent version of your dependencies. To do so, move your cursor to one of the lines then press Alt-Enter. In the popup menu, select the option to update to the newest version.

Comment: Thank you for your help and time

Comment: i do what you tell me to do   , but one more question the buildtoolsversion 25.0.2 is remplaced with ' defaultconfig ' is that normal ?

Comment: @kingjalal Can you build your app without any errors now? That is the final word on what is "normal".

Comment: @kingjalal Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for more information about what to do when someone answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your build tools version is below the minimum support thus it will be ignored in your `build.gradle`. Simply remove or upgrade the version of `buildToolsVersion` in your build.gradle.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but please can you tell me how to upgrade build.gradle .

Comment: and if i delete buildtoolsversion i will facing problems or not with it

Comment: @kingjalal No everything is fine.